# How to detect target iOS architecture in qmake?

Tags: ios, qt, qmake

I have a Qt Version that supports following ABI's (Qt Creator → Preferences → Build & Run / Qt Versions):

- arm-macos-generic-mach_o-32bit
- arm-macos-generic-mach_o-64bit
- x86-macos-generic-mach_o-32bit
- x86-macos-generic-mach_o-64bit

So, combining in a Qt Kit this Qt Version with different compilers I can build libs for all mentioned architectures.

At the same time the `mkspecs/qconfig.pri` contains:

```
host_build {
    QT_ARCH = x86_64
    QT_TARGET_ARCH = arm
} else {
    QT_ARCH = arm
}
```

So, in a `.pro` file I can not detect a target architecture (it is always `arm`). I can check `CONFIG` for `iphonesimulator` value and so detect arm/not arm architecture but there is still 32bit/64bit issue.

Is there a way to distinguish armv7/arm64/... builds in qmake (.pro file)?

Comment: For what reason do you need to distinguish them? I mean, for qmake system's pro files it's better to be as much crossplatform as possible. 
Btw, you can explicitly set build configuration, like this:
Add a target/build type in the Qt Creator, like ios-armv7; Also add something like `CONFIG += ios-armv7` to it's arguments.
Now you can perform architecture-specific actions in your .pro:
`ios-armv7 { ... }`

Comment: I need to do specific post-build jobs (that depend on arch type) such as sign and deploy installer, run specific VMs and launch tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method I found is:

Qt Creator → Preferences → Build & Run / Kits → Environment → Change...

Than set specific `IOS_ARCH` env var for each kit.

In `.pro` file:

```
IOS_ARCH = $$(IOS_ARCH)
!isEmpty(IOS_ARCH): TARGET_ARCH = $$IOS_ARCH
# then use $$TARGET_ARCH as usual
```