# Qt: different options in .pro file based on target architecture in WinRT

Tags: qt, qmake

Based on the target architecture different libraries (and other stuff) should be set. Therefore the .pro file includes this code:

```
contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, arm) {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/arm
}
else {
    contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/x64
    }
    else {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/x86
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that `contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, arm)` is never true. Is there a different way to get the ARM architecture for WinRT builds?

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect target iOS architecture in qmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338987/how-to-detect-target-ios-architecture-in-qmake)